# How do I programmatically add images to a node?

Tags: nodes, 9, batch-operations

I have a content type to which I added an image field. The database has a custom table with different columns, including the image ID.

Previously, I created a batch that writes data from this table to entity fields. It creates many nodes from the records in the table with filled fields. I need to do the same but for images. Part of the code from the batch is the following one.

```php
if (empty($entity_id)) {
  $info = [
    'type' => 'product',
    'title' => $productTitle,
    'field_name' => (string) $product->name,
    'field_product_cid' => (string) $product->cid,
    'field_custom_url' => $product->url,
    'uid' => 1,
    // here I need to add an image to the field_image field from the table
  ];
  $node = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->create($info);
  $node->save();
}
else {
  $storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node');
  $node = $storage->load($entity_id);

  // Change fields of node.
  $node->set('title', $productTitle);
  $node->set('field_name', (string) $product->name);
  $node->set('field_custom_url', $product->url);
  // and here change field_image if the node already exists
  $node->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someting like this:

```
$node = $storage->load($entity_id);
$image_source_path = '/some/path'
$image_target_path = 'public://some/path';
$image_data = file_get_contents ($image_source_path);
$image_alt = 'some alt text';
// Drupal 9 >= 9.3.0 or Drupal 10
$image_object = \Drupal::service('file.repository')
                    ->writeData($image_data, $image_target_path);
// Drupal 8
//$image_object = file_save_data ($image_data, $image_target);
$node->set('field_image', [
    'target_id' => $image_object->id(),
    'alt' => $image_alt,
]);
$node->save();
```